# How can I use the Default File Storage(S3) to upload files with Django FormTools form wizard?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-formwizard, django-storage

When uploading files, django-formtools Form Wizard, needs a place to temporarily store the until the user has completed all steps in the wizard.

The FormTools [documentation](http://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html?highlight=file_storage#formtools.wizard.views.WizardView.file_storage) shows an example of how to upload a file to a local folder on your server. The file_storage setting is required to upload files.

```
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage

class CustomWizardView(WizardView):
    file_storage = FileSystemStorage(location=os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'photos'))
```

We use Heroku and don't have access to local storage when uploading a file. We use django-storages and S3 to store all our files. I want to use django-storages to manage the upload process.

How can I just modify this view so that we use the default storage system to upload this file to a temporary location on S3?

Comment: Does your file gets saved at least on a temporary location in your production server? Or you are just able to get inmemory file object and not able to save it.

Comment: @ArpitSolanki Yes, the files are saved to a temporary location as configured in the code example. I just don't want it saved on the server; primarily because in production we cannot save it to the server. I don't believe in memory would work because formtools wants a physical file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This configuration will allow you to upload files directly to your django project's default storage backend. You can read about how it works in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/files/storage/#the-filesystemstorage-class).

```
from django.core.files.storage import DefaultStorage

class CustomWizardView(WizardView):
    ...
    file_storage = DefaultStorage()
```